# Baire $\sigma$-algebra generated by Z-sets.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

Given a completely regular Hausdorff topological space $(X,\tau)$ I want to be able to show that the Baire $\sigma$-algebra generated by the Z-sets is the same as the smallest $\sigma$-algebra for which all elements of $C_b(X)$ are measurable.

If X is compact then I believe this is correct. But I am struggling to see the truth in the more general setting.

Help would be much appreciated!

Z-sets are the sets of the form $\{x\in X | f(x)=0\}$ for some $f \in C_b(X)$

Completely regular means that for any closed set $K \subseteq X$ and for any point $x\in K^{c}$ then there exists $f \in C_b(X)$ such that $f(x) = 1$ and $f|_{K} = 0$ and $0 \leq f \leq 1 $.

In particular the bit that eludes me is showing the preimage of $(-\infty , a)$ is generated by Z-sets.

Comment: This seems to be related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/155261/baire-sigma-algebra

Comment: Thanks for the link, but there they are restricting to the case where X is compact, for which I have already realised the truth. (And additionally they don't assume complete regularity. So the cases are quite apart!)

Comment: Perhaps first show that $\{x\in X | f(x)\ge a\}$ is a Z-set, for $f \in C_b(S)$ and $a \in \mathbb R$.

Comment: @GEdgar If I could show that I would be immediately done! How do I?

Comment: Given $f$ and $a$, find $g \in C_b(X)$ so that $\{x\in X | f(x)\ge a\}=\{x\in X | g(x)=0\}$.

Comment: Aha, yes I know the definition of what I have to do. But actually finding that g is giving me problems.

Comment: Hint: the maximum of two continuous functions is continuous.